# SCOM: How to avoid reinitializize clienttcontext

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, scom

I have the following code in a console application:

```
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) { fillValues();Write2SP()}
```

and in Write2SP(), I always do that:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(WebUrl);
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Listname);
clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
// and then search and either insert or update an item
```

Is there a way to stop reinitialize clientContext every time?somewhere in Main(); and using static variables?

Thank you

Comment: If it is always pointing to the same list or web, pass that in as a parameter to your Write2SP method so you don't have to constantly be initializing a new instance of the same object.

Comment: Before or after ExecuteQuery()?